# Django PostgreSQL JSONField db_index error

Tags: django, postgresql, jsonb

My model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have created some objects and filled "data" field with some JSONs

Then I tried to create index for "data" field

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

Make migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Migrate

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Long traceback, and last line is:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: index row requires 8336 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25140), this is a limitation of the b-tree index. There is no simple solution to this. Indexing an entire JSONField also doesn't really make any sense. For what reason are you attempting to index the JSONField in the first place?

My recommendation would be to remove this index, as I doubt it is required. You may wish to try a more complex index, but Django's built in `db_index` is not capable of this. You'd have to create a more custom approach based on your situation.

Comment: Big thx for information.
I just wanted to make performance test.